# Static member 'mileTimeFor' cannot be used on instance of type 'RunningWorkout'

Tags: swift

```
struct RunningWorkout {
    var distance: Double
    var time: Double
    var elevation: Double
    static func mileTimeFor(distance: Double, time: Double) -> Double {
        return (distance/1600)/time  
    }
}
let running = RunningWorkout(distance: 3200, time: 30, elevation: 1100)
print(running.mileTimeFor)
```

I am getting error on my print line as:

> Static member 'mileTimeFor' cannot be used on instance of type 'RunningWorkout'

I am not sure how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You use static func with class instance, but must use with class itself. RunningWorkout. mileTimeFor(distance: Double, time: Double)

Comment: What you need is a computed property `var mileTime: Double { return time/(distance/1600) }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to access a `Type` function with the instance of the `Type` and it's wrong. When you declare a `Type` function (e.g. static) you must access it with the `Type` itself.

Now, your intention is to calculate something depending on the values of each instance. So you need to have an instance function. Like:

```
func mileTimeFor(distance: Double, time: Double) -> Double {
    return (distance/1600)/time
}
```

If you want to calculate the value using the above function, you need to pass the parameters also. That means, you have to invoke the function call as:

```
running.mileTimeFor(distance: 100, time: 60)
```

But you can change the function signature to be more compact, like:

```
func mileTimeFor() -> Double {
    return (distance/1600)/time
}
// call this as:
running.mileTimeFor()
```

Alternatively, you have another option in **Swift** as @Leo Dabus commented. You can have a `computed` variable that does the exact same as the function above (`mileTimeFor()`):

```
var mileTimeFor: Double {
    return (distance/1600)/time
}
// use this as:
running.mileTimeFor
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr: Remove the `static` keyword.